# Pass data from iframe to another iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a main page with 2 iframes on it. How do you send data from 1 iframe to the other iframe with links?

In this example, in the top iframe, how do i make a link to send song 1 name to the bottom iframe's function?

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
html,body {height:100%;}
.h_iframe1 iframe {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%; height:calc(100% - 60px);}
.h_iframe2 iframe {position:absolute;bottom:0;right:0;width:100%; height:60px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="h_iframe1">
        <iframe name="MainFrame" src="top.php" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="h_iframe2">
        <iframe name="BottomFrame" src="bottom.php" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

top.php

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

click here for song 1<br>
click here for song 2<br>
click here for song 3<br>

</body>
</html>
```

---

bottom.php

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script>
function playSong(song) { 
    console.log(song);
} 
</script>
</head>
<body>

audio player here

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75121285/). That question is also about sending data between iframes, and the answer I've given there may be of some use to you. Do you have any control on how the content in `top.php` and `bottom.php` is generated? If you do, perhaps there is an alternative to using iframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this, you can use [window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). The idea is to send a message from the top iframe and listen to it in the bottom iframe.

You can send messages directly from the top iframe to the bottom, or you can use index.html as a hub. In the latter case, you would send events from the top iframe to the parent (index.html), receive the event in the parent, and then send it to the bottom iframe.

Comment: I tried this but do not understand for iframes.

Comment: Smth like this https://codesandbox.io/s/test-iframe-8lkrni